# Detect input on canvas element in tkinter python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Is there any way to make the circles in the canvas change color when I click on them? I have 2 buttons which change the value of the varialbe "kleur". I want the collor of the circles which are canvas entities to change to the corresponding color in the variable "kleur". Is there a simple way of implementing this?

```
import tkinter as tk

mainWindow = tk.Tk()
mainWindow.title("Spelbord")

kleur = ""

def kleurverandering(kleur_button):
    if kleur_button == "green":
        kleur = "green"
    elif kleur_button == "red":
        kleur = "red"
    else:
        mainWindow.quit()


# frames

button_frame = tk.Frame(mainWindow, width = 25, height = 10)
button_frame.pack(side = "left")

grid_frame = tk.Frame(mainWindow, width = 220*4, height = 160*4)
grid_frame.pack(side = "right")


# make grid
# make separate tiles
tiles = []
for i in range(5):
    row = []
    for j in range(7):
        tile = tk.Canvas(grid_frame, width = 100, height = 100)
        tile.grid(row= i, column = j)
        tile_id = tile.create_oval(5, 5, 25, 25, fill="white", outline = "black")
        row.append(tile)
    tiles.append(row)

# buttons

green_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text = "Groen", width = 25, height = 5, bg = "green", fg =     "black", command = kleurverandering("green")).pack()
red_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text = "Rood", width = 25, height = 5, bg = "red", fg = "black",    command = kleurverandering("red")).pack()


mainWindow.mainloop()
```

I've tried many ways including canvas.bind etc but i cant get them to work.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few bugs in your code. Once those are fixed, using the `tag_bind` method of the canvas is the key to calling a function when an canvas item is clicked on.

First, in `kleurverandering` you must define `kleur` as global. Otherwise the function only changes a local variable that is invisible outside of the function.

```
def kleurverandering(kleur_button):
    global kleur
    ...
```

Next, you need to have the buttons use `lambda` so that the function is called when clicked rather than when defined.

```
green_button = tk.Button(..., command = lambda: kleurverandering("green")).pack()
red_button = tk.Button(..., command = lambda: kleurverandering("red")).pack()
```

You can then add a tag to each canvas item, and use `tag_bind` to bind an event to a function. First, we'll define the function. In the simplest case we can leverage the fact that the tag `"current"` will always be set to whatever was clicked on.

```
def click(event):
    event.widget.itemconfigure("current", fill=kleur)
```

Finally, we use `tag_bind` to bind it to the function.

```
tile_id = tile.create_oval(..., tags=("circle",))
tile.tag_bind(tile_id, "<1>", click)
```